# Javascript: "Top-level 'this' expression"

Tags: javascript, this

I get the following warning/hint/error when I have an object like this:

```
(
    function global(){...};
    function moreFunctions(){...};
)(this);
```

> "Top-level 'this' expression. This inspection reports instances of Javascript 'this' expression occuring outside of object literals or constructor bodies. Such this expressions are legal Javascript, and reference the top-level "global" Javascript object, but are largely useless." (by InspectionJS)

By the way, jQuery has the same with `(window)` instead of `(this)`.

I don't understand what it means. All I know is that everthing between the first `(` and second `)` is an object, but what's that addition?

I've got into this because I've just discovered a JS library <sup>[source](http://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/source/browse/mutation_summary.js)</sup> and somehow when it is included in my existing scripts everything just stops working. When I deleted that `(this);` part it didn't crash the page; but the library just didn't work.

Comment: That syntax won't work; to make it more explicit, your two functions should be inside the unnamed function in Neal's answer.

Comment: For more information, see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958383/why-do-many-javascript-libraries-begin-with-function

Comment: "All I know is that everthing between the first ( and second ) is an object" -- incorrect. Parentheses don't denote objects. Curly braces do: `{}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on the problem you're having but let me explain what I learned from Paul Irish's video on lessons from the JQuery source.

```
(function(window, undefined) {
})(this);
```

This is known as a self-executing function. The function definition is put in brackets. (anything can be put in brackets in Javascript almost all the time). Then, the second `()` immediately calls the function.

so it's like doing the following

```
function my_func(window, undefined){...}
my_func(this);
```

Now to explain the `this.` Usually, we wrap our entire program in such a self-executing function. The `this` while calling, and the window and undefined are pretty much just fixes for edge-cases when sharing the code space.
For example, someone could put something like

```
window = 0;
//or
undefined = 1;
```

suddenly, these very important global variables we rely on break. using this at the top level returns the window variable to the inner function. And since we don't pass any second variable to the function, undefined is back to its correct value.

Hope all this helped.

Comment: Actually, maybe it's not possible to mess with the value of window, but is possible to mess with undefined.

Comment: So if it's a self-executing function, can it make conflicts with other libraries such as jQuery or other? And if it doesn't have any name, how can I actually call a function like this?

Comment: So yeah it's a self executing function. It will not cause any harm to other libraries such as jQuery, since it doesn't populate the global namespace.
The function calls itself, so why do you want to call it?

Let me put it this way. you should wrap your entire Javascript code in a self-executing function this way, and put at the end of your html document. That way it start as soon as the document is ready. and it doesn't pollute the global namespace, and also your code stays safe from anything someone might do elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

It's complaining that you're using `this` outside of any function.

Inside a function, the use of `this` (generally) means that the programmer intended the function as a method (where `this` is the object that the method is called on), but outside a function, it's just a strange thing to do.

It's better to write `window` instead, to explicitly refer to the global object, rather than to rely on the fact that `this` implicitly refers to the global object when it's not used in a method call.

Answer (score 1):

This puts a whole chunk of code into a immediately executing function with its own scope.

For example:

```
(function(w){
    var apple = 'apple';
})(window);

alert(apple); //undefined
```